# How to Save Image in server

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to save an image in database but when I do the following it saves with dataURL, but that URL starts with `localhost`, how can I prevent it? I used React for frontend.

```js
uploadImage = (event) => {
    var imgSize = event.target.files[0].size;

    $('#img').attr('hidden', false);
    if (imgSize < 1000000 ) {
        this.setState({
            image: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
            imageSize: imgSize
        });
        document.getElementById("errImgUpload").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("errImgUpload").innerHTML = "Maximum image size 1Mb";
    }
}
```

```html
 <div className="form-group">
   <label for="file-upload" className="custom-file-upload">
     <span className="fa fa-upload"></span> Upload image
   </label>
   <input onChange={(event) => this.uploadImage(event)} name="file-upload" id="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*" />
   <span id="errImgUpload" className="text text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

The Blob is `http://localhost:10002/b46e96f5-83ce-4d10-b668-2bd038721b5a`, what is a blob?

Comment: you need to provide more info on the tech stacks. `reactjs` is front-end framework, what's your backend stack?

Comment: back end is .net

Comment: ...and are we supposed to guess how you code the .net part? share some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

`URL.createObjectURL()` creates a blob which is a binary representation of the file in the memory. It doesn't upload the file. I am not sure from where you got the code. You may want to read more about this at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).

Uploading requires a backend service to open an endpoint for you to send post data to. You need to use `<input type='file'>` tag to send the file as form data and set the service endpoint as the url in the form. Start with [this article](https://www.webdavsystem.com/javaserver/doc/resumable_upload/multipart_post/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your image data with `FormData`, like this:

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('image', files[0]);

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
}).then(...);
```

And blob is Binary Large Object, more detail you can find in MDN.